# Was Doom 1 (1993) open source?

Tags: open-game-license

I recall watching an interview with John Romero somewhere, or reading an article somewhere, a few years back in which it was clued that when ID Software made Doom there was a discussion if to make it open source or not so that gamers with adequate knowledge could mod and expand the game and thus keep the community growing and that eventually the developers agreed to make it "partially open source" or something of that sort.

Was Doom open source? Would the original license it had on its first release be considered FOSS by any standard today?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Doom was initially published as closed source and unfree software.

According to [this fan-made wiki](https://doom.fandom.com/wiki/Doom_source_code), the doom source code was initially published in 1997 under a proprietary license. This is long after the initial release and still had a non-free license.

They eventually decided to [revise the release](https://www.doomworld.com/idgames/source/doomsrc) and publish it as GPL, which definitely IS FOSS.